# How can i access array elements

Tags: php, arrays, json

Very noob here!
tried several tips from stackexchange, but with no luck.
I want to get :
"name 1",     "last name 1",
"name 2",
"last name 2",

```
{
  "iTotalRecords": 1092,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1092,
  "aaData": [
    [
      "July 7",
      "name 1",
      "last name 1",
      "joined jul 7",
      "by name"
    ],
    [
      "August 7",
      "name 2",
      "last name 2",
      "joined jul 9",
      "by name 2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start to do a json_decode of your datas. Add the parameters 'true' do get an array and not an object : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: A good answer produces the outcome sought for in the question. For simple leads forward, a comment is enough. Thanks for the effort.